# Require Writers Marketplace

Tags: business-writing

Can anyone please tell me a verified marketplace or community  where I can find writers filtered by their experience, work  for technical  and health related topics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping question.

Comment: hello this is not a shopping question its a suggestion question just want someone help if they know where i can find these writers thats it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have no idea what it's asking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to the help pages, seeking professional writers to write for you is not allowed here.

Comment: Closing the question because it's [asking for a website recommendation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and for the various reasons noted here by the community.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not specifically for writing about health-related topics, [Envato Studio](https://studio.envato.com/explore/content-writing) has a marketplace with writers who are available to write content on any subject.

You can contact the writers you like and ask if they can carry out the task you need help with.

You can also find copy editing, blog writers, press released, technical writers, cover letter help, and creative writing.

*Disclaimer: I have a shop set up there, but I am not self-promoting. I have no experience writing for health topics.*